# Is it possible to use typescript along with NW.JS and Angular.JS for desktop app

Tags: typescript

i am about to start a new desktop app based on Node-Webkit(nw.js). I am planning to use angular for its well known capability. wanted to know more about the possibility of using TypeScript in same project. My App is going to use few node packages(including custom packages written in C++) to interact heavily with OS. Moreover the app need to support mac and windows and need to be distributed over internet.
As i am relatively new to JS world, please provide some expert comments.

Thanks
Vashisth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> wanted to know more about the possibility of using TypeScript in same project.

There is absolutely no technical limitation here. Just create a NW.js app like you would in JavaScript and then change the `.js` file extension to `.ts`.

Note: TypeScript transpiles back to JavaScript, and if your JavaScript is valid then if you feed it to the TypeScript compiler you get back effectively the *same JavaScript*. More : http://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/why-typescript.html